# Variogram plot for Sill, Nugget, Range

Tags: r, time-series, analytics, gstat, covariogram

I'm working on Temporal-spatio data. Data is in STFDF structure.

I'm at the stage where applying variogram and try to determine Nugget, Sill, and Range from variogram plot that should look like this [image].

something like this:
[image]
However when I plot my variogram, it shows:

```
plot(vario, main="Flow")
```

[image]
And `plot(vario,map=FALSE, main="Spatio-temporal correlation")`
[image]
And `plot(vario,wireframe=T, main="Spatio-temporal correlation")`
[image]

How to get the plot that can define the range, sill and nugget!!  I couldn't define my parameters from these plots.
I used the variogramST function and tried too variogram function but both can't produce the plot I need.

```
vario<-variogramST(Flow~1,data=data,tunit="hours",assumeRegular=F,na.omit=T)
```

Is there any way to define Range, Nugget, and sill??

```
####### separable model, least squares fit
separableModel <- vgmST("separable",space=vgm(0.9,"Exp",100,0.1),time=vgm(0.9,"Exp",1000,0.1),sill=40) 
separable_fit <- fit.StVariogram(model=separableModel,object=vario)
plot(vario,separable_fit,all=T,map=F)
attr(separable_fit,"MSE") # calculate the Mean Absolute Error 
### product sum model, least squares fit
ProductSum <- vgmST("productSum",space =vgm(psill= 15000,"Exp",range= 0.07, nugget= 0),time=vgm(psill= 7500,"Exp",range= 0.07, nugget=0),k=0.000649771173341919) 
ProductSum_fit <- fit.StVariogram(model=ProductSum,object=vario)
ProductSum_fit
attr(ProductSum_fit,"MSE") 
plot(vario,ProductSum_fit,all=T,map=F)
plot(vario,ProductSum_fit,all=T)
plot(vario,ProductSum_fit, all=T, wireframe=T)


#### product sum model, manual fit
ProductSum_man <- vgmST("productSum",space=vgm(7500,"Exp",2e5,0,add.to=vgm(10,"Exp",9e3,0)), time=vgm(7500,"Exp",800,9.5,add.to=vgm(0,"Exp",850,0)),k=0.035) 
ProductSum_man_fit <- fit.StVariogram(model=ProductSum_man,object=vario) 
attr(ProductSum_man_fit,"MSE") 
plot(vario,ProductSum_man_fit,all=T,map=F)
plot(vario,ProductSum_man_fit,all=T)
```

Comment: If you can provide a reproducible example, you will have a higher chance to get the help you need.

Comment: I just added example

Comment: When I copied and pasted your code to my R condole, I cannot run your code, which means you code is not reproducible. As I mentioned in my previous comment, if you can provide a reproducible example, you will have a higher chance to get the help you need. Right now, the only thing I can say is: Good luck.

Comment: you need the library to run the code, and data as well. This is the code that produced the plot above. If it helps, I can provide you with data and the script.